How to List Files from Certain Directory /Python
Currently working on a little project. Basically, all I have is a program that asks for a certain network device type via user input (360 or 720) then it will ask for the MAC address of that certain device and validate that input with checking the directory and seeing if it exists, then list out the files under that specific directory.
Seem to keep running into this error: TypeError: listdir() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
Could be something very stupid I am missing here, but any feedback would be greatly appreciated!
Code I am working with currently:
while True:
    
    response = input('SCA Type (360/720):')

    try:
            response = int(response)
    except:
            print('Invalid SCA Type')
            continue
    if response =='360':
            os.system ("cd /var/SCAConfigs/SCA360/sites")
            continue
    if response == '720':
            os.system ("cd /var/SCAConfigs/SCA760/sites")
            continue
    break
folder_path = '/var/SCAConfigs/SCA%s/sites/' %(response)
os.listdir(folder_path)

choice = input("MAC: ")
folder_path = os.listdir(folder_path, choice, 'archive')


It looks like you're trying to concatenate the folder_path with a MAC then the archive folder to create something like /var........./MAC/archive/ to find files under this new path correct? look into os.path.join, os.listdir() only takes one argument.

Or to make your code more modern, use pathlib: Path(folder_path, choice, 'archive')
